# How to save the data from an object to a file in JSON format?

Tags: c#

I am using a lightbuzz library and there is a method called "BodyWrapper" which will have the data of the image captured by the Kinect 2.0. I want to save that data in a file.

I have used 
`Private BodyWrapper _captureBody;`

The content of the `_captureBody` is shown in the image. I want to save that content in a file so that when I need that data I can use it again.

I tried saving it in a .txt/.json/.csv file but I got nothing inside those file after creating, while saving it to a .json file I got error as:

> "cannot save to Json file as it should have any object or string".

Can anyone help me solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Content of _captureBody BodyWrapper]

Comment: do you mind to share the code that you wrote to save this data into a file?

Comment: Are you serializing the object before saving?

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize

Answer (score 1):

Without more details the best I can do is a generic example. I am a big fan of JSON.Net for serializing/deserialzing JSON. You can easily find it on Nuget under JSON.Net and it's using statement is Newtonsoft.Json (as you can see in the example below).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var exampleData = new ExampleClass
            {
                Property1 = "Bob",
                Property2 = 2,
                Property3 = DateTime.Today,
                Property4 = new List<SubExampleClass>
                {
                    new SubExampleClass
                    {
                        Property5 = "Something"
                    },
                    new SubExampleClass
                    {
                        Property5 = "Something Else"
                    }
                }
            };
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exampleData);

            const string testFile = @"c:\temp\example.json";

            File.WriteAllText(testFile,jsonData);
        }
    }

    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public int Property2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Property3 { get; set; }
        public List<SubExampleClass> Property4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubExampleClass
    {
        public string Property5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This writes a file with the format of

```
{
   "Property1":"Bob",
   "Property2":2,
   "Property3":"2017-12-19T00:00:00-05:00",
   "Property4":[
      {
         "Property5":"Something"
      },
      {
         "Property5":"Something Else"
      }
   ]
}
```

To which you can then easily read back into an object later on. Something like

```
const string testFile = @"c:\temp\example.json";    
var testData = File.ReadAllText(testFile);
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleClass>(testData);
```

Comment: You should probably mention where to get `Newtonsoft.Json` from.

Comment: Fair enough, adding it to the answer.